# UBO value changes value when passed to shader

Tags: glsl, buffer, shader, vulkan, imgui

I am trying to update the value of a uniform variable within my shader using an ImGui slider however the value I pass in is correct on the CPU side but when its at the GPU it becomes a negative value. I give an example of how I am setting this all up where `someVal` is the value being passed to the GPU which represents the `radius` value in the image I show (Naming was changed to help make things slightly clearer). This is what I am currently doing

```
static float ImGuiAdjustVal = 0.02f;

ImGui::SliderFloat("value: ", &ImGuiAdjustVal, 0.0f, 5.0f);

struct UniformObject {

    alignas(4) float someVal;
};

// update uniforms function

UniformObject ub{};
ub.someVal = ImGuiAdjustVal;

// both show same result and slider is able to adjust the value. The value just incorrectly makes it to the shader
std::cout << "Value: " << ImGuiAdjustVal << std::endl;
std::cout << "Sending to GPU" << ub.someVal << std::endl;

void* data;
vkMapMemory(device, uniformBufferMem[currentImage], 0, sizeof(ub), 0, &data);
memcpy(data, &ub, sizeof(ub));
vkUnmapMemory(device, uniformBufferMem[currentImage]);

// in my shader
layout(std140, binding = 1) uniform UniformObject {
  
    float someVal;
}ub;

float exampleProperty = ub.someVal;
```

In renderDoc my value is showing as becoming `-0.00295` instead of the set value of `0.02`
[image]

If I adjust the value using the `ImGui::Slider` the value will update in the print statements but the value will remain `-0.00295` in the GPU. I have tested this by using the slider to change the value and capturing a frame in renderDoc to see if the value changed. However, the value remained `-0.00295` as mentioned.

Comment: How do you synchronize shader access to the uniform data? And when do you update the data? Can you post that code part too?

Comment: @SaschaWillems Managed to fix the issue and posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was taking in an array of samples which was set to 64 but in my shader I had set it to 32. This caused my other variables to receive weird values.

```
struct UBOStruct {
    alignas(16) vec3 samples[64];
    alignas(4) float radius;
}

// shader 
layout(std140, binding = 1) uniform UBOStruct {
   vec4 samples[32];
   float radius;

}ubo;
```

The solution is to ensure all your values are being taken in correctly

```
struct UBOStruct {
   alignas(16) vec3 samples[64];
   alignas(4) float radius;
}

// shader 
layout(std140, binding = 1) uniform UBOStruct {
   vec4 samples[64];
   float radius;

}ubo;
```